# Addding elements to centered flexbox from left to right

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have a flex box to center 3 divs in the screen. all the three are wrapped around a flex container that has `justify-content: center` which centers them in the screen. However, since I am using animation and each div is being added one after another, the first div gets added at the center instead of the beginning, the second gets added such that both of the first and second are centered, and when the third is added, all of them are aligned such that the second div is exactly in the middle of the screen. I want to change that such that each div gets added in-place from left to right while all are centered in the screen.

[image: Current Behavior Flex Box]

React code:

```
function foo() {
  const [items, set] = React.useState([]);
  const transitions = useTransition(items, (item) => item.key, {
    from: { transform: "translate3d(0,-40px,0)" },
    enter: { transform: "translate3d(0,0px,0)" },
    leave: { transform: "translate3d(0,-40px,0)" },
  });

  React.useEffect(() => {
    for (let i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        set((items) => {
          const newItems = [...items];
          newItems.push({ key: i, code: rows[i] });
          return newItems;
        });
      }, 1000 * i);
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <center>
      <div class="flex-container">
        {transitions.map(({ item, props, key }) => {
          return (
            <animated.div key={key} style={props} class="flex-item">
              {item.code}
            </animated.div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </center>
  );
}
```

Styling:

```
.flex-container {
  height: 50vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;


  img{
    width: 20%;
    text-align: center;
  }
} 


.flex-item {
  flex-basis: 14%;
  align-self: center;

  margin: 12px;
  h4{
    font-family: Lato;
    font-weight:700;
    color: white;
  }
  p{
    color: white;
    font-family: Lato;
  }
}
```

Changing `center` to `flex-start` shifts everything to the beginning:
[image: Flex Start]

Adding fixed width doesn't work as well:

[image: Fixed Width]

Answer (score 0):

To solve your problem, simply align the cards the way you want them to look after they move, then apply the following CSS:

```
.card {
    position: relative;
    top: -100px;
}
```

If -100px is not enough, try -200px. The goal is that the cards will be off-screen at the top. Upon whatever action you desire, whether it be clicking a button like in my snippet below, or perhaps on page load, change the "top" property to 0, and it will place the card where it belongs in the normal flow of the page.

I additionally use the setTimeout function to delay each subsequent card, and the transition property to animate the movement smoothly since it seems like that is your desired goal.

```js
const left = document.getElementById("left");
const center = document.getElementById("center");
const right = document.getElementById("right");

function foo() {
  left.style.top = "0";
  setTimeout(function() {
    center.style.top = "0";
    setTimeout(function() {
      right.style.top = "0";
    }, 500)
  }, 500)

}
```

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

#container>* {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
  margin: 0 0.5em;
  position: relative;
  top: -100px;
  transition: top 1s ease-in-out;
}

button {
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="left"></div>
  <div id="center"></div>
  <div id="right"></div>
</div>
<button onclick="foo()" id="click-me">Click me!</button>
```